# Why pointer keeps pointing to the same address in all iterations of a loop?

Tags: c++, pointers

```
    map<int, set<int>**> st;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        set<int>* temp = new set<int>();
        set<int>** ptr = new set<int>*();
        //set<int>** ptr = (set<int>**)malloc(sizeof(set<int>*));
        ptr = &temp;
        temp->insert(i);
        st[i] = ptr; //at this stage st[0] .. st[i] points to the same ptr
    }
```

The vector of sets, st[0]...st[9] keeps getting overridden and points to the newly generated ptr for every single loop.
Am I missing something?

Comment: I do not see a vector in your code. You are not trying to do a C-style array-like construct with pointers, are you?

Comment: `map<int, set<int>**> st` -- I hope that you're not actually trying to write code like this in an actual application.  Having a `set<int>*` as a data item is bad enough, but having a `set<int>**` as a data item -- maybe you should rethink your design.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Someone said three-stars programmer?

Answer (score 0):

With

```
set<int>* temp = new set<int>();
set<int>** ptr = new set<int>*();
```

you are creating the `set`s pointed to by the pointers freshly in each iteration of the loop. I.e. nothing is overwritten, it is even worse, it gets completely destroyed after each iteration.
That is why `temp->insert(i);` will always insert into a freshly created and still empty set.
The line `ptr = &temp;` however will always set the local pointer `ptr` point to the address of the loop-local pointer `temp`, which can easily always end up on the same address. (Think of the stack, though that is not strictly defined by C standard.)

Answer (score 0):

You store dangling pointers in your map `st`.

```
ptr = &temp;
```

will take the address of the temporary variable `temp`. In the next iteration of the loop a new value will be assigned to `temp`, but the *address of temp* will stay the same, thus `ptr` will always point to the same temporary variable.

When the loop ends and `temp` goes out of scope you have dangling pointers and undefined behaviour follows.

I'm not really sure why you want to use pointers, especially double pointers here. I think you can drop all the pointers and let the map manage memory for you.

```
map<int, set<int>> st;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    set<int> temp;
    temp->insert(i);
    st[i] = temp;
}
```